# tag <a onclick = file.php> and refresh page

Tags: php, forms

I have a login form; this is a part of my code:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" >
     <label>Username</label>
     <input type="text" name="username"/>
       <br>
     <label>Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="password"/>
       <br>
     <div class="log"><a class="btn btn_red">Login</a></div>
</form>
```

What I expect is that this form redirect me to the "login.php" file, but it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Thank u all.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: In which situation should that form "redirect" you somewhere? There is no button in it

Comment: By *"redirect"* do you mean submit the form?

Answer (score 4):

You have an anchor (with no `href` attribute) and no button.

You need a submit button

```
 <div class="log"><button class="btn btn_red">Login</button></div>
```

Comment: I think he might want a `submit`, which makes sense considering the inputs and how is named his link

Comment: how can I use "href" attribute?

Comment: This option can work, as long as he calls a javascript function that submits the form.

Comment: @tshimkus — `type="submit"` is the **default**

Comment: @LorenzoTosone — To submit a form? You can't, at least not sanely. Use a submit button.

Comment: @KebabProgrammer — Well, he isn't, and using JS is a less reliable and pointlessly complex approach to it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" id="form1">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
          <br>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
          <br>
        <div class="log"><button type="submit" class="btn btn_red" form="form1" value="Submit">Login</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is more or less the same as the answer I gave half an hour ago, just with absolutely no explanation, a pointless `type="submit"` (that's the default), a pointless `form="form1"` (the button is inside the form already), and a pointless `value="Submit"` (there is no `name` attribute).